# Dynamically select rows and union them using postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a question in `postgresql`; I've tried using a `cursor` for the following but could not get this to work.

I have a large employee table that has multiple columns, one of them being the company name, see below:

[image: master table]

The master table is not sorted by date, it needs to be sorted during the filtering process. This table can have more than 100,000 records; I want to create a 2nd table that will have only some of the records (by each company name) - essentially, get the rows for each `company name` by `pre-defined number of records` and then union the tables together into a new table. My pre-defined records table would look something like this

[image: required records]

Ideally, I could have more than 1000 companies in my original, master table and I might need only 50 companies and some records for the 50 companies that will be defined in my records table. How can this be done in `postgresql`

Sample Output: Records are the number of records that are mentioned in the `pre-defined records desired` table and are sorted by date

[image: output]

Comment: It will be good if you provide the sample of the output you want your query to return based upon these 2 tables.

Comment: @mukund thank you for the suggestion - I added the sample output. Please let me know if you know how this could work. I've tried using `cursor` but could not get it to work

Comment: are you not simply filtering your master table based upon the entries in predefined records table ? 
```select * from employee_table where company_name in (select company_name from pre_defined_records_table) ```

Comment: And if you also want number of records then simply join them ? 
```select * from employee_table t1 left join pre_defined_records_table t2 on t1.company_name = t2.company_name 
where t1.company_name in (select company_name from pre_defined_records_table) ```

Comment: No, it's based on the `number of required records` i.e. the select query should only return `x` number of records which are specified in the 2nd table. So `Apple` has 3 records and `Amazon` has 2 in the output as compared to 6 and 5 records I would get if I just did what you said in your comment.

Comment: Okay. But how do you know which records you select from master table ? Apple has 6 records but out of them which 3 records are to be selected ? Because your pre-defined records table gives information on only the number of records.

Comment: So this is an ordered set, I order the table by a `date` column and selected them with that. Let me add that to the question to be more clear and concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can left join and filter the master table with the help of predefined number of records table. Then create a rank-ordered by date which can further nested and filtered using where condition.

```
select t3.* from (

    select 
        t1.* 
        , t2.number_of_records 
        , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.company_name ORDER BY t1.date_column asc) ranks
    from employee_table t1 
    left join pre_defined_records_table t2 
        on t1.company_name = t2.company_name
        where t1.company_name in (select company_name
    from pre_defined_records_table)
    
) t3
where t3.ranks <= t3.number_of_records
```

I have used the dummy names for your columns and tables as the sample data is not reproducible.
PS - Check also `Dense_Rank()` function.

Comment: Thank you @mukund. This is largely there, I would need to tweak it a little, but this points me exactly how to go about it. I was using `cursor` which had made it overly complicated in `postgresql`, it would have been easy with a cursor in Microsoft SQL. Thank you!